# Standard method to find and edit front-end files in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have recently been asked to take over the administration of a website that is built on CakePHP 3.x.

I have never worked with CakePHP before. Everything I have read talks about using a command line interface, but I haven't done this since I was in Uni.

I discovered a Dashboard on the website where I can enter or edit the products, but I was wondering about the pages on the site.

I had to change some phone numbers in the footer of each page and it was only hunting through the files that I found `src/Template/Element/footer.ctp` and edited this.

Is there some way of editing the pages without finding the individual files?

Comment: It will depend on how it's the thing done. I recommend you first read about the framework and familiarize yourself. Otherwise it will all be a "hunting through"

Comment: I think the short answer to this is going to be no. But like @yBrodsky said - once you learn about the framework (and this website's code in particular) there's a lot less guesswork. For instance, the path to the file you needed displays the obvious logic of how to get there (Template = how the page looks, Element = a particular part of the page, Footer = well, you get it :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you're referring to (the command-line stuff) is for when you're [baking files](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html), running [shell tasks](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html#shell-tasks), doing [database migrations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html), installing things [via composer](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#keeping-up-to-date-with-the-latest-cakephp-changes), or using the [built-in local server](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/server-shell.html)...etc. There are other uses too, but editing front-end files is not usually one of them.

Though there are methods for altering local files via command line, for the things you're talking about, like editing a footer, or other pages (.ctp "Template files" in Cake 3), it's standard practice to just do that manually.

See the standard path for template files in these examples:

```
src/Template/Users/profile.ctp
src/Template/Pages/contact.ctp
src/Template/Layout/default.ctp
```

A "layout" file usually fetches the header, content, and footer.

As you've found, there are also [Elements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements), which are smaller chunks of code that are reusable across one or more Template files.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Much appreciated.